# How do I handle undefined class objects passed as function arguments?

Tags: scala, jackson, generic-programming, case-class, json4s

The variable entered as a function parameter is an instance of the case class.
In this situation, can you do something like JsonMethods.extract [variable]?

```
// I do not know if the "Any" keyword is appropriate. Or, Class [_]?
def func(a: Any) {
   val json = """{"c_1":"hi","c_2":"bye"}"""
   JsonMethods.parse(json).extract[a]           // ERROR
}
```

If the above function(func) is provided, users would be able to:

```
case class Test(var c_1: String, var c_2: String) {}

val t = Test("", "")
func(t)
println(t.c_1) // "hi"
println(t.c_2) // "bye"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know json4s so my stuff might not be on point. But here's something important the thing passed to `extract` is actually a type-parameter not a value-parameter. I think what you want to do is

```
JsonMethods.parse(json).extract[Test]
```

With the Type passed in extract you tell json4s into what structure your json should be put. In your case the case-class `Test`